# Return key on event handler double firing across two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hit the "return" key on .searchtext, the dialog opens and then immediately closes. Why is the return key on the "keyup" event in the first function also firing in the "keyup" event inside the validateSearchText function? And how can I avoid this?

```
$('.searchtext').on('keyup', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    processSearchText($(this));
  }
});

const validateSearchText = (element) => {
  if ($('.searchtextwrap .invalidmissing').length) {
    let dialog = new $.Zebra_Dialog('Please enter a word or phrase to search.');
    $('body').on('keyup', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        dialog.close();
      }
    });
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};

const processSearchText = (element) => {
  if (validateSearchText(element)) {
    //do search
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you can try by taking out the event attachment `dialog.close` outside the `validateSearchText` function

```
let dialog;
$('.searchtext').on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    processSearchText($(this));
  }
});
$('body').on('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    dialog.close();
  }
});
const validateSearchText = (element) => {
  if ($('.searchtextwrap .invalidmissing').length) {
    dialog = new $.Zebra_Dialog('Please enter a word or phrase to search.');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};

const processSearchText = (element) => {
  if (validateSearchText(element)) {
    //do search
  }
};
```

Comment: I think moving it out is a good idea, however I'm still having the issue. I inserted some console.log statements so I can see what is going on. I appears to be a timing issue. Things happen in this order: (1) The script detects the enter key on the search box, so it correctly runs processSearchText. (2) Because the search box is empty, it correctly opens the dialog. (3) The script also detects the enter key on the body, so it immediately closes the dialog, which is incorrect. I basically don't want the pressed enter key to do both (1) and (3).

Comment: I fixed this by adding a 500ms timeout so that the dialog isn't closed immediately.